# Переделать foreach в for

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, я новичок в php, как мне переделать двойной foreach в for.

```
<div class="block-body">
            <?php if (!empty($player->progress)) :
                foreach ($player->quests as $key => $val) :
                    foreach ($player->progress as $key => $val1) :?>
                        <div class="mission-title">
                            <?php
                            echo "<br>PROGRESS: " . $val1->amount;
                            echo "<br>QUESTS: " . $val->date;
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что надо не "переделать" один бессмысленный код на другой, а надо данные вывести нормально?

Comment: Почему бессмысленный код? Все данные берутся из БД, я просто скинул отрывок кода, с которым мне нужно помочь

Comment: Потому что этот код повторяет одно и то же по сто раз. А если уж этот код нормально работает, то тогда надо написать в своем вопросе, почему вдруг резко понадобилось его переделывать

Comment: У меня 2 foreach, $player->progress равен 10, $player->quests равен 3, почему-то эти два foreach умножаются и выводят 30 записей, хотя должны только 10. Вот я и подумал, что может мне поможет for

Comment: 1. Без разницы foreach или for. 2. Цикл у вас не двойной, а вложенный. 3. Вложенные циклы так и работают. Сначала для верхнего цикла перебираются все элементы, которые нужно, затем для каждого варианта (на каждой итерации внешнего цикла запускается цикл внутренний и для каждой итерации внешнего перебирает все свои варианты. Если внешний аргумент имеет у вас 10 вариантов, и для каждого из них есть по три варианта внутри, получаем именно 30 значений. Теперь опишите задачу - что и как именно вам нужно вывести, как и предложил камрад Ипатьев. Учитесь формулировать вопросы.

Comment: @Quazimorda только наоборот - сначала для верхнего цикла берется *один* элемент, потом перебираются все элементы внутреннего. Дальше из верхнего берется второй элемент и снова все для внутреннего - и так далее. А "сначала для верхнего цикла перебираются все" - это как раз то, как автор представляет себе работу этих циклов (неправильно).

Comment: @Ипатьев Верно. Это и хотел сказать. Очевидно, мне тоже следует учиться формулировать )))

Comment: $player->progress и $player->quests выполняют подключение к таблицам progress и quests, соответственно. И в той, и в другой таблице есть столбец quest, в этом столбце есть определённые значения, которые мне нужно вывести. Сейчас они выводятся 3 раза и при этом повторяются, а мне нужно сделать так, чтобы они выводились 1 раз и не повторялись

Comment: Например, и в той, и в другой таблице в столбце quest есть записи quest_d1, quest_d2, quest_d3 и т.д, нужно сделать, чтобы они выводились только один раз